# Custom rule for browser dictionary

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, microsoft-office, internet-explorer, spell-check

Many companies and organizations combine two words, and capitalize them both, forming their name (ex: **SuperUser** and **StackExchange**).  Both words individually are spelled correctly, however because there is no space, the browser gets confused, and underlines them, letting us know they think they are misspelled.

How can I get Google's **Chrome** or Mozilla's **Firefox** or even Microsoft's **Internet Explorer** and **Microsoft office** to recognize the capital letter in the middle of a word as beginning a new word, and therefore not marking the word as misspelled (unless the 2nd word is misspelled, ex: **SuperUsr**)

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is a great idea, but as far as I know there is no way to write that rule into the browser spellchecker. There are ways to add exceptions (for instance in FireFox you can right click and say "add to dictionary") but to create a rule that checks capitalized sections within a word is something I have not heard of. It would be great to suggest this to browsers developers.

I hope someone else on here can offer you better advice

Comment: I know its a great Idea, thanks for the support, I'm looking really to see if someon's made an add-on or something... Welcome to [SuperUser](http://superuser.com) btw...

Comment: @[user7777777](http://superuser.com/users/105046/user7777777) Questions that you like, you can "up-vote"

Comment: It's a great idea until you submit something with two words accidentally stuck together into something that's isn't really spelled right, and your spell checker didn't warn you. ;)